# Android App Development Beginner

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a rookie in Android. Tried to create an android project for an app that displays a simple `"Hello World!"` message. However when I run the Run the code, it shows the below 18 errors :

`ActionBarActivity` cannot be resolved to a type

`ActionBarActivity` cannot be resolved to a type

`ActionBarActivity` cannot be resolved to a type

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name `'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.`

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable

The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved

The method `getMenuInflater()` is undefined for the type `Droid2Activity`

The method `getSupportFragmentManager()` is undefined for the type `Droid2Activity`

The method `onCreate(Bundle)` of type `Droid2Activity` must override or implement a supertype method

The method `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` of type `Droid2Activity` must override or implement a supertype method

The method `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)` of type `Droid2Activity` must override or implement a supertype method

FYI I am using eclipse Indigo SR2. And have installed Android API15. Please let me know how to go about this and get them resolved.

Thanks and Regards,
Manoj Naik

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: It looks like you've missed some installation steps. You might want to go through the installation process as described in the official documentation. Either that or you just need to clean your project and avoid incorrect syntax.

Comment: if my answer helped mark it as so for visitors to this site to get the answer that they are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  When I ran the SDK Manager, as FeatheredOrican
suggested, it indicated that the support library was installed but it was
out of date. Updating it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the support library to your project

1.Download support library from SDK Manager

2.Right click project in eclipse -> add support library

Compatibility issues may occur I recommend Updating to Keplar